# How do I get mouse coordinates on Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to read the X coordinate of a mouse click on Fabric.js.

Here is my code. The console logs `undefined` every time.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
  getMouse(e);
});

function getMouse(e) {
  console.log(e.clientX);
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The best fix is [this](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getPointer) method

Implementation:

```
function getMouseCoords(event)
{
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
  var posX = pointer.x;
  var posY = pointer.y;
  console.log(posX+", "+posY);    // Log to console
}
```

Comment: How to make this work on mozzila
I am having problems with  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

Comment: What's the exact problem you are having? Need more info.

Comment: Thank you for writing. I posted the querion and got answare on following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636200/how-to-get-fabric-js-canvas-mouse-cordinates-on-mozzila

Answer (score 8):

To get coordinates based on set width and height on the canvas itself, use layerX and layerY property.

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(options) {
    console.log(options.e.layerX, options.e.layerY);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! do you have an example that will take canvas pan and zoom into account?

Comment: Using `canvas.getPointer(options.e).x` seems to take canvas pan and zoom into account.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
function getMouse(e) {
    console.log(e.e.clientX);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PKfZ4/1/)

**Updated,** as `canvas events` takes the `options` as an `argument` not `an event` like,

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options){
   getMouse(options);// its not an event its options of your canvas object
});


function getMouse(options) {
    console.log(options);// you can check all options here
    console.log(options.e.clientX);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Why e.e.clientX?

Answer (score -1):

just use e.e.clientX

or

e.e.clientY

for getting positions

Comment: There is already another answer which uses same solution with an explanation. This answer doesnt add anything new

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help:

```
//Convert To Local Point
function toLocalPoint(event, canvas) {
var offset = fabric.util.getElementOffset(canvas.lowerCanvasEl), localX = event.e.clientX - offset.left, localY = event.e.clientY - offset.top;
return new fabric.Point(localX, localY);
```

}

Comment: This is certainly a viable method but it adds an unnecessary layer of complexity when you can use a simpler, more elegant method that is already pre-defined.