# How to get fabric.js canvas mouse cordinates on mozzila

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

This is the code that is working on google chrome

```
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
var posiX = pointer.x;  
var posiY = pointer.y;  
posiX=Math.round( posiX );
posiY=Math.round( posiY );
```

On mozzila i am getting "TypeError: event is undefined" and it is pointing at 
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dime,

Please use mouse events like this:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(event){
   var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
   var posiX = pointer.x;  
   var posiY = pointer.y;  
   posiX=Math.round( posiX );
   posiY=Math.round( posiY );
});
```

'**event**' has to be defined as part of the function parameter. Please make sure you have the same logic.